# Fullpage.js not loading in mobile device in odoo website

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, odoo-website

I  developed one website in odoo.. with scrolling animation fullpage.js but, my fullpage.js is not loading in mobile device..any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide your page html and the contents of the JavaScript file you are saying about.

Answer (score 0):

http://46.101.145.46:8069/en_US/ this is url of my website and its working properly now...

fullpage.js was disabled for mobile device in plugin file.. i have enabled it and its working thanks,